# On-screen keyboard with function keys

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, function-keys, on-screen-keyboard

Is there a way to add the function keys to the on-screen keyboard in Windows 7? If not, is there an alternative program that has the function keys? [image: Windows 7 on-screen keyboard]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What's wrong with pressing the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 3):

If you press the `Fn` button on the right of the keyboard the function keys will be displayed. On windows 8 the button is on the right of the keyboard. The Function keys will be displayed on the number keys.

Answer (score 3):

Hit that Fn button on the right hand side of the keyboard and the F1-F12 keys will appear.